# How to disable field list at runtime in performancepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, performancepoint, fieldlist

I have a dashboard that I am displaying, and whenever my users click on a pivotchart or pivottable the field list automatically pops up. How can I prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use ad hoc analysis tools such as pivottables and charts in a dashboard like this, the field list will always appear.

If you are able to use static data then render it out to that format and replace what you currently have with it.

Comment: i am rendering the chart as an image but the field list still appears.

how can I do drill-down reporting in a tabular format without a pivottable?

Comment: In PerformancePoint, I don't believe you can get the dynamic features you want (such as drill-down) without also showing the field list. Some MS products like Project Server that offer similar functionality allow you to initially hide the field list, but it is still possible to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the chart in Dashboard Designer.  In the **Commands and Options** dialog box select **Chart Workspace** in the drop down list.  Once you do that, the tab **Show/Hide** should appear.  On that tab you can clear the checkbox for the Fields List.  Clear any other checkboxes in that dialog, and close the window.  Click on your chart in DD and make sure the fields list (and any other dialog boxes - ie Commands and Options, Drop Zone, etc) don't appear.  Publish your chart and you should be good to go.